# Relationship between variance of population and variance of average of population

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, descriptive-statistics

I'm curious if there's a fixed relationship between the variance of the average of a sample and the variance of the sample. 
Here, I'm taking the variance of the trailing two rows of Series A and Series B (Var of Sample) and comparing it to the variance of the trailing two a averages (Var of Average).
If provided the variance of the sample, could we compute the variance of the average knowing only `n`?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 'no.'
Examining this case when the two series are the same, we see the Var of Sample obviously becomes zero, but the Var of Average remains volatile.

[image]